# FOR in cmd works fine but .bat close immediately

Tags: for-loop, cmd

Why does this close immediately ? is it becouse of ERROR?
I want it to kill umcs when it can
in cmd it terminates process than prompts
ERROR: The process "UCMS.exe" not found multiple times and again terminates process

for /L %i in (1,0,2) do @ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul & taskkill /F /im "UCMS.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Due to the bizarre nature of the batch parser, in batch files the for loop variable must be specified with *two* percent signs, like this:

```
for /L %%i in (1,0,2) do @ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >nul & taskkill /F /im "UCMS.exe"
```